# ko.mapping (update array issue)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the problem with ko.mapping
1) On client ViewModel:

```
var self = {
  books: ko.observableArray([ {id : 1, title: "A"},{id : 2, title: "B" } ])
};
```

2) From server (array of objects) :

```
var data = [ {id : 1, title: "C"} ]
```

3)I need to  replace data only if it exists:

```
[ {id : 1, title: "C"},{number : 2, title: "B" } ]
```

3) I try to using ko.mapping plugin, but result  `[ {id : 1, title: "C"} ] => data replace self.books`

```
var mappingOptions = {
  key: function (data) {
    return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.id);
  }
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, self.books);
```

Thx:)

Comment: So you want to keep the existing books? Not possible, at least not with the mapping plugin. After new data is mapped, the target observable will be equal to the new data. If there are two elements `A` and `B` in the target list and the server only sends one element `C`, then after the mapping operation there will be one element `C` in the list. Look at the server data as the *reference*, not as a diff. Let the server send `A` and `B` as well if you want to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

You can (probably) use the ko.mapping plugin for this, but I think it'll benefit you if you try to solve this in plain javascript first. It's not much code, and at the very least you'll better understand what kinds of things the plugin does under the hood.

Your `books` array needs to be merged with an array of updates (`data`). You use the `id` property to check for equality. So, in short, you'll have to:

- Loop through your updates
- Find the old book that matches the id
- Replace it with the new book
- Set the `books` array with the updated list so knockout can figure out what has changed

A straightforward implementation of the update function:

```js
var books = ko.observableArray([ 
  {id : 1, title: "A"},
  {id : 2, title: "B" } 
]);

var updateBooks = function(updates) {
  var oldBooks = books();
  var newBooks = oldBooks.map(function(book) {
    var update = updates.find(function(update) {
      return update.id === book.id;
    });
    
    return update || book;
  });
  books(newBooks);  
};

ko.applyBindings({
  books: books,
  updateBooks: updateBooks
});

updateBooks([{ id: 1, title: "C" }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: books">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text:id"></span>
    <strong data-bind="text: title"></strong>
</ul>
```

This implementation will work if you don't mind performance requirements, and if you can be certain all of the `id`s in the updates are already available in the `oldBooks` (i.e. the updates do not contain *new* books). It also creates a new array with a combination of new and old book objects. This makes it harder for knockout to render the list efficiently.

With some more work, you can make a book viewmodel with an observable `title` property. By using an `id` based map, you can speed up the update cycle.

```js
var Book = function(options) {
  this.id = options.id;
  this.title = ko.observable(options.title);
  
  // Instead of creating new Books all the time,
  // we update its observable property so only the changed values
  // are re-rendered
  this.update = function(options) {
    this.title(options.title);
  }.bind(this);
};

Book.create = function(options) { return new Book(options); };

var BookList = function(bookData) {
  this.books = ko.observableArray(bookData.map(Book.create));

  // Compute an object that stores each book by id.
  // Whenever the books array changes, this object is updated.
  // Access a book by calling: this.bookMap()[bookId]
  this.bookMap = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return this.books().reduce(function(map, book) {
      map[book.id] = book;
      return map;
    }, {});
  }, this);
};

BookList.prototype.updateBooks = function(updates) {
  // Apply each update
  updates.forEach(function(newBook) {
    // Find the book by id in our map
    var bookRef = this.bookMap()[newBook.id];
    if (bookRef) {
      // The book has its own viewmodel, with an update method
      bookRef.update(newBook);
    }
  }.bind(this));
};

var data = [ 
  {id : 1, title: "A"},
  {id : 2, title: "B" } 
];

var vm = new BookList(data);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.updateBooks([{ id: 1, title: "C" }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: books">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text:id"></span>
    <strong data-bind="text: title"></strong>
</ul>
```